# Cron Jobs Linux row deletion

Tags: linux, cron

I'm running this script;

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM XXX WHERE email='$Email'";

if($count==1) // fails
if($count==0) // succeeds

If successful

mysql_query ("INSERT INTO XXX (email) values ('$Email'");
```

Then proceeds onto the next script.
So, it checks to see if you have already ran this script in the past on that account, if you have your email is stored then you can't run this script ever again on that same email.

However, after this script has been processed I want it to delete the row created for the email after 6 hours.

So that after 6 hours they may run the script again.. I've been enlightened that I need to use Cron jobs for this, But I'm not sure how.. Any help is highly appreciated!

Many regards, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Either delete all emails from that table every six hours, or you'll need a timestamp to indicate when the email "expires".

Comment: Okay. I've added to my querys;

`code    $date0=time();
   $date1=date('G : i ');`
It now inserts the time of the execution like this "3:12" for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
0 0,6,12,18 * * * /path/to/mycommand
```

This means starting from hour 0, 6, 12, and 18 the cron job would run. That would be the cron needed to do what you want.

Depending on which linux version you are running you will need to see how to actually create the cron job.

Comment: What if it runs while there is no entrys for that email? Like if they don't re-use the script exactly as the 6 hours ends. 
Since they will be re-entering the email row at various different times aslong as its been 6 hours since the first or previous time.

Also, what would be the command? Excuse me if I sound rude. Cron job's isnt my thing lol. But I really appreciate your time ^_^

Comment: What options do you have for creating a cron job? If your host allows you to have cron jobs they typically how a FAQ on setting one up on their service, if this is a server you have root access to which version of linux is it running? -- As for the what, your script would handle all of those if/then issues.. this was simply how you configure a cron job to run every 6 hours no matter what.

Comment: CentOS release 4.9 (Final). I see, well there is around 100-200  entry's per day, at all different times, when finished only 4 per-person. I need each row to self delete 6 hours after being added, because there's no way everyone will be able to do it at the same time. Thanks once again!

Comment: If you have crontab installed you can just use that to create the cron job. I think crontab -l will list cron jobs and crontab -u yourusernamehere -e will allow you to add/edit the cron list where you can add the above information.

Answer (score 0):

I would think `at now +6 hours` is a better choice here.